# IBM Domino and variables X-Forwarded-Proto-F5

Tags: 301-redirect, ibm-domino

Domino server receive requests with variable in header [X-Forwarded-Proto-F5].
I would like to do some tricks depends of value there (either redirect requests or not).

Is it possible to do redirects based of some variables in request's header using only IBM Domino server?

If no, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've not found a way to do that with native IBM Domino capabilities, so we setup an additional server (nginx) between LoadBalancer and Domino and configured everything on nginx instead.

Answer (score 1):

The Notes C API toolkit includes an interface called DSAPI that allows you to add your own code into the HTTP stack, intercept requests, get access to headers, and take actions.

Comment: Thanks, that's an option, however I would really like to avoid using DSAPI. It will take few days for me to do that and I want to believe there is a nice and easy solution to achieve that.